# How to change the badge number in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to change the badge's value.
The values and the Id's I get perfectly in Json via HTTP call.

Inside the `for`, i have this: `val = items[key];`

**VAL** is the new value for the badge and **items[key]** is the specific badge to change.

In jQuery, I did like this:

```
$("#"+items[key]).text("").text(val);
```

And in Ionic 2, how can I do this?

The API works fine. All values is returned correctly.

**My `userpage.html` is:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="person" item-left></ion-icon>
        Profiles
        <ion-badge id="profiles_total" item-right>0</ion-badge>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="create" item-left></ion-icon>
        Blogs
        <ion-badge id="blogs_total" item-right>0</ion-badge>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**My `userpage.ts` has this:**

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
var r = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.post('mobapi/mob.php?action=get_totals', {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.json().success){
            var items = data.json().items;
            var key;
            var val;

            for (key in items) {
                val = items[key];
            }

            resolve(true);
        } else {
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `userpage.html` like this:

*Note: I am going to explain later*

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-icon name="{{item.icon}}" item-left></ion-icon>
        {{item.name}}
        <ion-badge id="{{item.id}}" item-right>{{item.count}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In the code above, I created a loop, using this parameter in the element that I want to repeat: `*ngFor="let item of items"`

```
"item" is the variable that I created to access the data.
"items" is the object created in code below. This variable contains all items to repeat.
```

I changed my TS File `userpage.ts` like this:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
var r = new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.post('mobapi/mob.php?action=get_totals', {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.json().success){
            this.items = data.json().items;
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
});
```

In the code above, I saved the data object in the variable:

```
this.items = data.json().items;
```

This variable is used in the HTML to do the loop (`*ngFor="let item of items"`).

An important information:

You need to declare the variable `items`, below the open class, like this:

```
export class UserPage {
    items: any;
```